# How can I cut segments of audio/video while keeping the other track intact in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am a newer user to ffmpeg, but I have a slightly complicated use case for it. I need to be able to cut multiple sections out of a video and/or multiple sections out of the audio, with the actual length of the video and audio files remaining intact (e.g. the audio would cut out but the video continues, or the video continues but the audio cuts out). I have been slowly learning about complex filtergraphs, but a little help would be VERY much appreciated.

this is currently my super basic "test script" to see if I can get it to work (in it's actual use case, the timestamps will be variables in a python program)

```
    ffmpeg -i bdt.mkv -filter_complex 
    [0:v]trim=start=10.0:end=15.0,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[0v];
    [0:a]atrim=start=10.0:end=15.0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[0a];
    [0:v]trim=start=65.0:end=70.0,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1v];
    [0:a]atrim=start=65.0:end=70.0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a];[0v][0a][1v]
    [1a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] out.mp4
```

Comment: Not clear what you want. Do you want to insert silence or black screen at specified time range?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do both, so an answer to either one would be helpful :) Edit: I just realized I didn't change my title to reflect that, sorry O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use timeline option `enable` with the [`between`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) expression. For video, you can use the `overlay` filter.

```
-vf color=black[b_];
    [b_][0:v]scale2ref[b][in];
    [in][b]overlay=shortest=1:enable='between(t,1,2)'
```

For audio, use the `volume` filter:

```
-af volume=0:enable='between(t,1,2)'
```

You'll need to escape `'`s. If you want to do more complex on/off's build up `enable` option using additional expressions (see the link above).

These aren't the only way to achieve the effect, but the easiest I could think of atm.

Comment: This has worked beautifully, and saved me a lot of heartache on my project. As an ffmpeg noob, I salute you. Thank you so much!!